# Supabase and NextJS Route API Handling Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, supabase

I am using NextJS and Supabase and this is the error that it shows:

> ⨯ Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to
> Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes
> are not supported.
> at stringify ()  ⨯ Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components.
> Classes or null prototypes are not supported.
> at stringify () digest: "1376061893"

**app/api/Orders/route.ts**

```
    import { createServerComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
    import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
    import { cookies } from "next/headers";
    import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
    
    export async function GET (request: NextApiRequest) {
      const cookieStore = cookies()
      const supabase : any = createServerComponentClient({ cookies: () => cookieStore })
      const {data: {session }} = await supabase.auth.getSession();  
    
      const {data, error } = await supabase
      .from('orders')
      .select()
      .eq('id', session?.user.id)
    
    
       if (error == null) {
            return NextResponse.json({ data });
        }
        return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message });
    
    }
```

****Calling it here: components/Orders/ViewOrders.tsx:****

```
import OrderList from "./OrderList";

export default async function ViewOrdersByWaterStation({}) {
 

        try{
          const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/Orders`,{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          })

          const data = await response.json()
      
          return Response.json({ data })

        }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
    return ( 
        <div>
         <OrderList orders={orders} />
        </div>
     );
}
```